# How can I remove the duplicate using statement?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a bunch of methods that do the following:

```
using(var cn = new Connection())
{
    //custom code
}
```

Is there a way I can still use the `using`, but just call my custom code?

Comment: i really don't know what you are trying to achieve... what is your custom code?

Comment: @stefankmitph - I didn't think that his small sample was that hard to understand. `Custom code` just meant that I had multiple methods with identical using statements but the code between them was the only thing different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about creating a **new method** encapsulating your `using-block` and putting an [action-delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    doCustomCode(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("customCode #1");
    });

    doCustomCode(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("customCode #2");
    });
}

private static void doCustomCode(Action action)
{
    using (var con = new Connection())
    {
        action();
    }
}
```

In case you need somethig more specific than a simple action, just modifiy the according parameter.

Comment: I had a feeling it might be something like this.  Is this the typical way or are there other options? Thanks.

Comment: In most cases when I do code I write multiple using statements rather than using my given answer. IMO I don't see that much advantages on using a method like `doCustomCode(..)`

Comment: I would agree.  It is more concise, but I don't think much advantage is gained, plus, it seems like better practice to force the user to explicitly put the using statement. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following:

1. Wrap your custom code in a method.
2. Use a `try { } finally { }`
3. Aspect-Orientanted-Programming using a Proxy
4. Use  IL editor like [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/)